# How to calculate 2D rotation from 3D matrix obtained from sensor TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR (to lock one axis rotation)

Tags: android, 3d, opengl-es, 2d, android-sensors

I want to build application which uses phone sensor fusion to rotate 3D object in OpenGL. But I want the Z axis to be locked therefore I want basically to apply 2D rotation to my model.

In order to build 2D rotation from the 3D matrix I get from `SensorManager.getRotationMatrixFromVector()` I build rotation matrix for each axis as explained on the picture:

[image]

I want to apply 2D rotation matrix which would be `R=Ry*Rx` however this seems not working. But applying `R=Rz*Ry` works as expected. My guess is that `Rx` values are not correct.

To build the `Rz`, `Ry`, `Rx` matrices I looked up values used by `SensorManager.getOrientation()` to calculate angles:

```java
values[0] = (float) Math.atan2(R[1], R[4]);
values[1] = (float) Math.asin(-R[7]);
values[2] = (float) Math.atan2(-R[6], R[8]);
```

So here is how I build matrices for each axis:

```java
private val degConst = 180/Math.PI

private var mTempRotationMatrix = MatrixCalculations.createUnit(3)

override fun onSensorChanged(event: SensorEvent?) {
    val sensor = event?.sensor ?: return
    when (sensor.type) {
        Sensor.TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR -> {
            SensorManager.getRotationMatrixFromVector(mTempRotationMatrix, event.values)

            val zSinAlpha = mTempRotationMatrix[1]
            val zCosAlpha = mTempRotationMatrix[4]
            val ySinAlpha = -mTempRotationMatrix[6]
            val yCosAlpha = mTempRotationMatrix[8]
            val xSinAlpha = -mTempRotationMatrix[7]
            val xCosAlpha = mTempRotationMatrix[4]

            val rx = MatrixCalculations.createUnit(3)
            val ry = MatrixCalculations.createUnit(3)
            val rz = MatrixCalculations.createUnit(3)
            val sina = xSinAlpha
            val cosa = xCosAlpha
            val sinb = ySinAlpha
            val cosb = yCosAlpha
            val siny = zSinAlpha
            val cosy = zCosAlpha
            rx[4] = cosa
            rx[5] = -sina
            rx[7] = sina
            rx[8] = cosa
            ry[0] = cosb
            ry[2] = sinb
            ry[6] = -sinb
            ry[8] = cosb
            rz[0] = cosy
            rz[1] = -siny
            rz[3] = siny
            rz[4] = cosy

            val ryx = MatrixCalculations.multiply(ry, rx)
            mTempRotationMatrix = ryx
            MatrixCalculations.copy(mTempRotationMatrix, mRenderer.rotationMatrix)
            LOG.info("product: [" + mRenderer.rotationMatrix.joinToString(" ") + "]")
            val orientation = FloatArray(3)
            SensorManager.getOrientation(mTempRotationMatrix, orientation)

            LOG.info("yaw: " + orientation[0] * degConst + "\n\tpitch: " + orientation[1] * degConst + "\n\troll: " + orientation[2] * degConst)
        }
```

The question is what I am doing wrong and what values to use for the `Rx` matrix. Is my math applied to this problem broken? Also interesting would be to know how value of `event.values[3]` is related to build rotation matrix in `SensorManager.getRotationMatrixFromVector()`.

In theory operation `R=Ry*Rx` should give me correct rotation but it is not the case.